# Convert these clamp CSS variables into working SCSS variables?

Tags: css, variables, sass

I would like to use these variables as SCSS variables instead of CSS variables in my project. However, I can't really find a way to convert them properly. Does anyone have a clue how I could achieve it?

Here are the variables I'd like to convert:

```
--step--2: clamp(0.91rem, 0.89rem + 0.1vw, 0.96rem);
--step--1: clamp(1.09rem, 1.05rem + 0.21vw, 1.2rem);
--step-0: clamp(1.31rem, 1.24rem + 0.37vw, 1.5rem);
--step-1: clamp(1.58rem, 1.46rem + 0.59vw, 1.88rem);
--step-2: clamp(1.89rem, 1.71rem + 0.89vw, 2.34rem);
--step-3: clamp(2.27rem, 2.01rem + 1.29vw, 2.93rem);
--step-4: clamp(2.72rem, 2.36rem + 1.83vw, 3.66rem);
--step-5: clamp(3.27rem, 2.75rem + 2.56vw, 4.58rem);
```

Comment: Why you want to do this? it doesn't make a lot of sense because there is no clamp() logic in SASS

Comment: Mainly because I don't really like having regular CSS variables and SCSS variables mixed in my file. And I also do prefer the SCSS variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the values in SCSS you could just do something like:

```
$step-0: clamp(1.31rem, calc(1.24rem + 0.37vw), 1.5rem);
```

You'd need the extra `calc` in there as the addition is a run time calculation. `rem` and `vw` are dynamic units in the browser and SASS can't add them in the compiler.

This also unfortunately means that SASS can't compute the values so if you wanted to use them in further calculations they'd also need to be run time calculations using `calc`:

```
.foo {
  width: $step-0 + 1px; // Doesn't work
  width: calc(#{$step-0} + 1px); // Does work
}
```

Comment: Oh alright, thank you!